# How to populate a search bar and table view with multiple functions

Tags: ios, swift

I have a search bar and a table view and I want to put names of songs , artists and albums in them. Whenever I type in the search bar it only filters threw album names and not songs, or artists. How would I get them all to show up because only getAlbumName() is showing up? I just added Search.swift.

```
 var search = [Search]()

 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for:  indexPath)
    
    if (searchActive) {
        cell.textLabel?.text = search[indexPath.row].getCleanName()
        cell.textLabel?.text = search[indexPath.row].getArtistId()
        cell.textLabel?.text = search[indexPath.row].getAlbumName()
    } else {
        searchActive = false
    }
    return cell;
}
func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {
    search = search.filter({ (songName) -> Bool in
        return songName.songname.lowercased().range(of: searchText.lowercased()) != nil
   })

    if(search.count == 0) {
        searchActive = false;
    } else {
        searchActive = true;
    }
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
    self.tableView.reloadData()
    }
}
```

Search.swift

```
class Search {

var search: Search!

var id = Int()
var name = String()
var cleanName = String()
var artist = String()
var album = String()


init?(id:String, name:String, artist:String, album:String) {
    self.id = Int(id)!
    self.name = name
    self.cleanName = name.replacingOccurrences(of: "_", with: " ").replacingOccurrences(of: ".wav", with: "")
    self.artist = artist
    self.album = album
}

func getId() -> Int {
       return id
   }
   
func getName() -> String {
         return name
     }

   func getCleanName() -> String {
       return cleanName
   }

   func getArtistId() -> String {
       return artist
   }
   
    func getAlbumName() -> String {
       return album
   }
 }
```

Comment: Unrelated but all those `get..` functions to access properties are pretty cumbersome. And where does the `init` method fail?

Comment: The code doesn't compile anyway. Is this the real code? Where is `self.name` (in the init method) and `songname` (in the filter closure) in the class?

Comment: @vadian It does, I edited it out but its back. The filter closure doesn't let my put artist, or album in it . It says I can only except one argument.

Comment: It does definitely **not** compile. The line `self.name = name` will cause an *unknown identifier* error. I know what your problem is. You have to add `range(of` expressions with `||` (OR operator) for the other properties in the filter closure.

Comment: @vadian I added self.name = name. Do you mean something like this search = search.filter({ (songName || artist || ablum) -> Bool in != nil

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to search for multiple properties you have to add `range(of` expressions for each property

```
search = search.filter({ song -> Bool in
    return song.cleanName.range(of: searchText, options: .caseInsensitive) != nil ||
           song.artist.range(of: searchText, options: .caseInsensitive) != nil ||
           song.album.range(of: searchText, options: .caseInsensitive) != nil
})
```

Consider that `search = search.filter` makes actually no sense because you overwrite the array with the filtered result and if you tap the *backspace* key you'll get unexpected behavior.

And most of your code in the class is redundant. The methods to access properties are pointless. It can be reduced to

```
class Search {
    let id : Int
    let name, cleanName, artist, album : String
    
    init(id: String, name: String, artist: String, album: String) {
        self.id = Int(id)!
        self.name = name
        self.cleanName = name.replacingOccurrences(of: "_", with: " ").replacingOccurrences(of: ".wav", with: "")
        self.artist = artist
        self.album = album
    }   
}
```

You can get the album easily with `song.album`